# Law of Return and Step Children

Tags: state-of-israel, aliya-laaretz

The 1970 amendments to Israel’s Law of Return regarding “Rights of members of family” state that right of return also vest in “a child and a grandchild of a Jew, the spouse of a Jew, the spouse of a child of a Jew and the spouse of a grandchild of a Jew.” [See here](https://www.knesset.gov.il/laws/special/eng/return.htm)

In this context does “child” also include step child or just biological child? I'm not familiar with Israeli family law and an Internet search did not yield an immediate answer to this question.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Israeli law (which need not, and often does not, match Jewish law) is not on topic here.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/ maybe they know something.

Comment: @DoubleAA. This question is about Aliya and Aliya is part of Judaism. “Thus says Cyrus king of Persia, ‘The LORD, the God of heaven, has given me all the kingdoms of the earth, and he has charged me to build him a house at Jerusalem, which is in Judah. Whoever is among you of all his people, may the LORD his God be with him. Let him go up.’”

Comment: Note that the Law of Return is secular only and does not follow halacha. For example, the child of a Jewish man and nonJewish woman is not Jewish but can be Israeli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepchildren must be allowed in under the Law of Return, witness a very specific case described below:

https://www.jta.org/archive/behind-the-headlines-despite-grievances-cuban-olim-feel-lucky-to-be-in-the-jewish-state-2

> Sotolongo came to Israel with Violeta Perez Nieto, his second wife, and four stepchildren. His stepson Ewduin Perez, 24, is also not technically Jewish. But when Jews began reviving community life in the early 1990s after Castro became more tolerant of open religious practice, the family started going to synagogue. Perez’s grandfather was Jacobo Perez Meshulam, who immigrated from Turkey to Cuba and was a founder of the local synagogue.